# Overdrive WMA file will not play on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, wma

The WMA files from Overdrive.com will not play on my Windows 7 media player.  They will play on Vista. I've tried opening with realPlayer but get the same error message.

The messages is "Windows Media Player cannot play any items in the playlist.... with a "Web Help" button.  That give the following message.

Windows Media Player C00D11B1

then instructions to check the sound device. I have done that and the device (VIA High Defininition Audio) is working and no updates are available.

Comment: which version? x86 or x64?

Comment: Looking for solutions on the internet I have seen that others have had exactly the same problem.  

Just to be clear.  The files will play on my Vista machine which I have set up to play WMA files with real player.  I've just checked and the files will also play with Windows Media player on my Vista machine.

Comment: Which version of what?

Answer (score 1):

Alibarsdad, I use the full download and in it you will have the option to do a full, basic or standard. It is set for standard but I change it to ( LOTS of stuff ) to get most all codecs and it also has a list that you can checK the boxes for more codecs that you may need. DO A RESTORE POINT BEFORE INSTALLING JUST IN CASE!

Also I had this problem and I downloaded the VLC player and it plays the files just fine.